# Why often a struct's tagName differs from the typedef's name?

Tags: c, struct

Sometimes I see code like this (I hope I remember it correctly):

```
typedef struct st {
    int a; char b;
} *stp;
```

While the usual pattern that I familiar with, is:

```
typedef struct st {
    int a; char b;
} st;
```

So what's the advantage in the first code example?

Comment: Is the asterisk really an asterisk in the source code? Or just a wildcard?

Comment: Take it as a wildcard please. For some reason I remember an asterisk, but that doesn't compile.

Comment: Do you perhaps mean `struct _st` instead of `struct *st`?

Comment: Most likely you mean following, as unwind answered: 
typedef struct st {
    int a; char b;
} *stp;

Comment: Why don't you edit the question so that it makes sense now you know what you meant to ask?

Comment: @Clifford: I didn't edit my question because now whoever will read these comments will not understand what we talked about. But I edited anyway :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably mean this:

```
typedef struct ST {
  /* fields omitted */
} *STP;
```

The asterisk is at the end of the statement. This simply means "define the type STP to be a pointer to a struct of this type". The struct tag (`ST`) is not needed, it's only useful if you want to be able to refer to the struct type by itself, later on.

You could also have both, like so:

```
typedef struct {
  /* fields omitted */
} ST, *STP;
```

This would make it possible to use `ST` to refer to the struct type itself, and `STP` for pointers to `ST`.

Personally I find it a very bad practice to include the asterisk in typedefs, since it tries to encode something (the fact that the type is a pointer) into the name of the type, when C already provides its own mechanism (the asterisk) to show this. It makes it very confusing and breaks the symmetry of the asterisk, which appears both in declaration *and* use of pointers.

Comment: `typedef` ing `*` is useful for opaque types, which might be implemented as pointers, but could have been implemented as numeric ids just as well; if done sensibly, information hiding through `typedef` is a good thing

Answer (score 3):

It's a habit that stems from the time when typedef names and struct tagnames were in the same namespace. See http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2008/03/26/8336829.aspx

Comment: Do you have another reference hinting that there was such a time?  I'll try to dig out in DMR home page and some other old documentation I've. to confirm.  I don't remember it.  (What I remember was that the member namespace was unique for all struct and union, that explain the prefixes in members names of Unix structures).

Comment: No, but I consider OldNewThing fairly reliable.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are talking about :

```
typedef struct{
   int a;
   char b;
} object, *objectPointer;
```

This means that (new) type objectPointer is a pointer to `struct` (object) defined above. Its easy to declare pointers to object `struct` this way. For instance,

```
objectPointer A = (objectPointer)malloc(sizeof(object));
A->a = 2;
```

Now, A is a pointer to struct object and you can access its variables as described above.
In case, objectPointer was not defined,

```
struct object *A = (struct object *)malloc(sizeof(object));
A->a = 2;
```

So, I guess objectPointer is more **intuitive** and **easy** to use.

Comment: No, it means that something of type `object` is a pointer to `struct _object`.

Comment: +1. In the first code: Does a semicolon omitted at the end of the struct? (line 4)

Comment: @Dor: yes. semicolon after struct.

Answer (score 1):

I hope that the first code would say a compiler error ,

Answer (score 0):

I see no good reason for the typedef name be different from the tag name.

Now, the reason for which the tag name needs to be typedefed if you don't want to use

```
struct tag v;
```

but

```
tag v;
```

is probably an historical one.  For as long as I remember, C had typedef but I don't know if it was true when `struct` have been introduced (handling of typedef is a nuisance in the C grammar).  In the old code I've seen, using typedef for struct isn't done, and there are things like unix

```
struct stat;
int stat(const char*, struct stat*);
```

which would break with an automatic typedef.  One those are introduced, changing is quite difficult (yes, C++ has automatic typedef but C++ has special wording to handle that case of overloading and it would be yet another complication).